# IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file

Tags: java, ioexception

I have opened a file, then I am locking a file region, I wish to update a value and then rewrite this back to the file. I am getting the following error message when trying to write to the file I have locked:

```
java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another 
process has locked a portion of the file
```

Code example:

```
// Now lets get a lock on the first 10 characters       
try( RandomAccessFile raFile    = new RandomAccessFile( cbooking, "rw" );
FileChannel channel         = raFile.getChannel(); 
FileLock lock           = channel.lock( 1 , 10, true)   ) {  
    // Write the new value to the file
    byte[] bytes = "           ".getBytes();
    raFile.write( bytes );
}
catch ( IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // TODO Add logging - Could not gain character lock on the file!
    return false;
}
```

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer?  I'm running into the same thing on Windows and it's mildly infuriating

Answer (score 0):

If you think it is really not being locked by another instance, Try FileChannel.open instead of getting channel via RandomAccessFile